# Laravel echo/pusher not sending ping when receiving data

Tags: laravel, echo, laravel-8, pusher-js, laravel-websockets

I'm running a [laravel websocket](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) and have a connection over wss.

I am running commands on the server, and the commands are logged in a file. Each line is also sent over a websocket to the front-end so I can view it. Each laravel-command has it's own file and broadcast-channel.

Commandlogger:

```
class CommandLogger implements Logger {

    public $commandname = '';
    public $broadcast   = false;

    public function __construct($commandname, $broadcast = false) {
        $this->commandname = Str::camel(Str::slug($commandname));
        $this->broadcast = $broadcast;
    }

    function log($message) {
        $message = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').": ".$message;
        file_put_contents(storage_path("logs/commands/$this->commandname.log"), $message.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($this->broadcast) {
            event(new CommandLogCreated($message, $this->commandname));
        }
    }
}
```

In Vue.js I listen with Echo(which implements pusherjs):

```
Echo.private('logs.commands.' + command)
    .listen('.command-log:created', event => {
        this.log[command] += event.message + "\n";
        let splitLog = this.log[command].split("\n");
        let splitLength = splitLog.length;
        if(splitLength > 200) {
            splitLog = splitLog.slice(splitLength - 200, splitLength);
        }
        this.log[command] = splitLog.join('\n');
        this.trigger++;
    })
    .error(error => {
        console.log(error);
     });
```

The issue I'm experiencing only happens when the command is sending a lot of messages to echo.

At a normal rate, with some pauses between the messages, echo does the ping-pong and the connection remains receiving messages.

At higher message rates, is seems echo is not sending the ping-pong and my socket silently stops receiving data. After it stops receiving it starts ping-ponging as if nothing happend. No disconnect has occured on both server and client.

Websocket messages(notice it stops at 205000, gives no error and resumes ping-pong):

[image]

Actual command output(at 230000 and still running):

[image]

If I refresh the page, I will receive messages again.

I've updated the `websockers:serve` command (vendor/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/src/Console/Commands/StartServer.php) directly and disabled the pongtracker:

```
protected function configurePongTracker()
{
    //$this->loop->addPeriodicTimer(10, function () {
    //    $this->laravel
    //        ->make(ChannelManager::class)
    //        ->removeObsoleteConnections();
    //});
}
```

Then I rebooted the websocket and tried again. This time, no matter how fast I was sending messages in, echo keeps receiving messages.

### TL;DR:

My conclusion is that echo should ping-pong in between receiving messages from the server, because currently it seems to fail at doing so, and the websocket cleans the connection eventually without disconnecting. How can I either force echo to do the ping-pong, or make sure the server does not clean the connection without running the risk of having runaway connections?

### Update 1:

I've been diving a little more into the `Startserver.php` file and found this:

```
public function removeObsoleteConnections(): PromiseInterface
{
    if (! $this->lock()->acquire()) {
        return Helpers::createFulfilledPromise(false);
    }

    $this->getLocalConnections()->then(function ($connections) {
        foreach ($connections as $connection) {
            $differenceInSeconds = $connection->lastPongedAt->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now());

            if ($differenceInSeconds > 120) {
                $this->unsubscribeFromAllChannels($connection);
            }
        }
    });

    return Helpers::createFulfilledPromise(
        $this->lock()->forceRelease()
    );
}
```

So that explains why I stop receiving messages, but there is no disconnect. It just unsubscribes the channels I'm listening to silently(can't see this on front-end) and keeps the connection alive.

I've also created an [issue on github(laravel/echo)](https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/308) because I do think this is unwanted behaviour. I'm just not sure if the issue lies within echo, or within pusher js.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through this. check your channel name and type, and make sure you have access. Also, check that there are no other js files interfere with your `app.js` file like what happened to me. check this [laracasts question](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-echo-not-working-1) out

Comment: I believe my access is correct, my broadcast/auth is successful

Comment: I've also verified i'm only injecting `app.js` once( its a single-page app) and tried the suggestions in your referred question, without success. If you have more tips i'm happy to try :)